# Is there a way to get the list of existing tags from a WordPress blog using AtomPub?

Tags: wordpress, atom-feed, atompub

I'd like to be able to query a Wordpress blog for a list of existing tags so that they can be offered at the time that a new post is being created. Is this possible through AtomPub with Wordpress? I'm finding the documentation for Wordpress AtomPub support to be lacking. I'm wondering if this is more of a restriction on AtomPub than on the Wordpress implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Atom does not have a concept of "tags", only ["categories"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.2). As AtomPub is based on it, it only specifies [a request for categories](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023#section-7).

The WordPress AtomPub implementation [calls `get_categories()` directly](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-app.php#L370), which, of course, defaults to the `category` taxonomy. However, you can filter the arguments via `get_categories_taxonomy`, and change the `taxonomy` argument to an array that includes `post_tag`. You would of course only enable this filter when there is an AtomPub request.

When a post is created or updated WordPress only looks at the categories, so you will have to add the non-category terms yourself. You can do this by hooking into the `atompub_create_post` and `atompub_put_post` hooks, which get the WordPress post ID and the full entry the client sent, which includes all terms.